# Android, how to generate stack trace on unhandled error

Tags: android

My yacht race tactician app is tough to debug in the lab as I don't have the resources to build a system to simulate the wide range of input data experienced on the water. (It relies on environmental inputs such as wind speed, gps location, compass, boat speed etc. being supplied via bluetooth in NMEA format. )
On the water, and so not connected to the IDE, it still occasionally crashes, but all I get is "Unfortunately, {application} has stopped". What I'm looking for is the method to have the app dump a stack trace on crashing for later review and analysis. 
Obviously if I knew where the suspect code was, I could surround with try/catch, but the problem is I don't know where the weakness(es) lie. What I'm looking for is a global "on error" handler.

Comment: There's a variety of libraries that will detect crashes and upload the results to a server.  I'd look into using one of them.  At least one of them should be able to store it for later if its on the water and internet isn't available.

Comment: Alternatively, there are many apps on Google Play that will give you access to logcat - from there you can read through your app's logs and find the stack trace of any unhandled exceptions and errors.

Comment: Thanks guys. "...variety of libraries..." and "...many apps..." point me in the right general direction, but some specific recommendations would have added some much appreciated icing to the cake.

Comment: @user3047912 I didn't want to recommend one app over another, because their features can vary and only you could pick exactly which one(s) match your needs, but for what it's worth I have had good results with "aLogcat" and "CatLog". (PS. If you tag us in your comments, we'll be notified and can reply quicker)

Comment: Mark Ormesher I tried a few of the logcat apps but it seems they all need root to acces the logcat buffers on 4.1. So i'm still "at sea".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the crash reporting functionality baked into the Google Play store: https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#reviews-reports

If for some reason this doesn't work for you, the basis of these "libraries that will detect crashes" is [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). One such library that seems to be popular is ACRA: http://acra.ch/

Comment: ACRA took me a few hours to get my head around- especially the bit about using an Application, but it does what I want and much more. I'm now posting a detailed crach report back to my web site for later analysis.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google analytics.

For Caught exceptions use:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions#caught

For uncaught exceptions (crashes) use:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions#uncaught